# adding a value to an attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am sure this is simple, I just dont seem to be able to get my head around it. I am trying to add a value of an attribute on click.

So there is this button

```
<input domain_id="9" class="home_send_but" value="send" type="button">
```

And when clicked

```
$('.home_send_but').click(function(){
    domain_id = $(this).attr('domain_id');
    $('#send_but').attr('domain_id').val(domain_id);
});
```

It should add the domain_id of 9 to:

```
<input domain_id="" id="send_but" type="button" value="Send Now">
```

However, the domain_id attribute for send_but remains as null.

So how do I add a value to an attribute?

And yes, I know I should be using data attributes.

Comment: Is `domain_id` global because you didn't declare as a variable: `var domain_id = $(this).attr('domain_id');`

Comment: You should be using data attributes instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 4):

You can set attributes in jQuery by using the `attr()` method in this way:

```
$("#send_but").attr('domain_id',domain_id);
```

Source: [jquery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Thats great, I almost thought of trying it, should have.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Your code should be `$('#send_but').attr('domain_id',domain_id);`